# WordPress: $wpdb->get_results(); returns wrong results after the first loop

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am currently working on a plugin in Wordpress (latest version).
Now everything went just fine except this one thing when hooking into GravityForms.

Here is my code:

```
function DbUpdateServices($services){
$choices = $services->choices;
print_r($choices);
global $wpdb;
$allValues = array();
foreach($choices as $choice){
$text = $choice["text"];
$value = $choice["value"];
$allValues[] = $value;
$name_exists = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM quotation_diensten WHERE dienstNaam='$text'", ARRAY_A);
echo("SELECT * FROM quotation_diensten WHERE dienstNaam='".$text."'");

if($wpdb->num_rows == 0){
  $value_exists = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM quotation_diensten WHERE dienstValue = $value", ARRAY_A);
  if($wpdb->num_rows == 0){
    echo "No rows found";
    $wpdb->insert('quotation_diensten',
      array(
        "dienstNaam" => $text,
        "dienstValue" => $value
      ),
      array('%s','%d')
    );
  } else {
    echo "Row found";
    $wpdb->update("quotation_diensten",
      array(
        "dienstNaam" => $text
      ),
      array( "dienstValue"=> $value
      ),
      array("%s")
    );
  }
} else {
  echo "($value,$text) Bestaat,<br>";
  $wpdb->update("quotation_diensten",
    array(
      "dienstValue" => $value
    ),
    array( "dienstNaam"=> $text
    ),
    array("%d")
  );
}
$wpdb->flush();
echo "<hr>";
//delete
$allServices = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM quotation_diensten", ARRAY_A);
foreach ($allServices as $service) {
  if(!in_array($service["dienstValue"], $allValues)){
      //verwijderen
      $wpdb->delete( "quotation_dienstaanvraag", array('dienstenID'=>$service["dienstenID"]) );
      $wpdb->delete( "quotation_bedrijfsdiensten", array('dienstenID'=>$service["dienstenID"]) );
      $wpdb->delete( "quotation_diensten", array('dienstenID'=>$service["dienstenID"]) );
  }
}
}
}
```

This is the content of `$choices`:

```
array(3) {
   [0]=>
      array(3) {
         ["text"]=>
            string(9) "Service 1"
         ["value"]=>
            string(1) "1"
         ["isSelected"]=>
            bool(false)
      }
       [1]=>
          array(4) {
             ["text"]=>
                string(9) "Service 2"
             ["value"]=>
                string(1) "2"
             ["isSelected"]=>
                bool(false)
             ["price"]=>
                string(0) ""
           }
       [2]=>
           array(4) {
               ["text"]=>
                   string(9) "Service 3"
               ["value"]=>
                   string(1) "3"
               ["isSelected"]=>
                   bool(false)
               ["price"]=>
                   string(0) ""
             }
          }
```

The first time the foreach loop gives me a row back which is correct.

The second and third time it says `0` rows.

This is my database structure:

```
dienstenID      | dienstNaam | dienstValue
221                Service 1 |    1
351             |  Service 2 |    2
352             |  Service 3 |    3
```

Me and my colleague couldn't figure out why. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the following line is definitely wrong:

```
$name_exists = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM quotation_diensten WHERE dienstNaam='$text'", ARRAY_A);
```

Why? Because a variable name within single quotes is not interpreted, you are passing the string value `$text` to the database which is certainly not what you want. I guess if you change this, it will solve your problem.

Change it by using `$wpdb->prepare` for your code. It is bad practice to write variables into the SQL yourself.

Comment: `$name_exists = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM quotation_diensten WHERE dienstNaam='%s'",$text);`
still returns 0 rows on second request.

Comment: You have to remove the single quotes.

Comment: `$name_exists = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM quotation_diensten WHERE dienstNaam=%s",$text);`

Comment: Okay so i removed those single quotes. Now the first one gives the result, but the second one 'Service 2' still gives me 0 rows as a result. but it is 100% certain in the database. It just removes the old row and creates a new one with the exact same data.

Comment: Try `$wpdb->show_errors( true )` before calling get_results, in order to see if there are any errors. Does the query work if you directly execute it within the database?

Comment: the show_errors doesn't return me anything so I assume no errors. Also when i execute the query directly i get a result. Never had this problem in any other plugin/code before.

Comment: Before $name_exists =  ... did you try var_dump($text). Are you sure it is "Service 2"?

Comment: result: `string(9) "Service 2"`

Comment: Strange ... what is the result of $wpdb->last_query right after you have executed the query?